# Как сделать ссылки без домена в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Имеется сайт на wp, все ссылки: новости, рубрики, используют ссылки с доменом
`https://site.ru/name_news` как их преобразовать в `/name_news` - без домена?

Как я понял, все ссылки выводятся через `the_permalink(); the_permalink(); get_term_link()`

Нашел способ

```
function my_permalink() {
    echo substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('')));
}
```

Но он не удобен, нужно лазить по всему шаблону, искать вывод ссылок и менять на эту функцию

Есть ли более простое решение?

Зачем?
На сайте есть поддомены и когда находишься на поддомене, все ссылки видут на основной домен.

Как сделаны поддомены?
С помощью плагина `Custom Post Type UI` добавлен раздел 'Филиалы'
С помощью плагина `Advanced Custom Fields` добавлены доп. поля для 'Филиалов':

1. Адрес сайта
2. Город
3. Номер телефона

В `function.php` получаем текущий домен, на котором находимся, ищем этот домен в филиалах бд, если находи передаем данные этого филиала в шорткод и для модуля SEO

В зависимости от поддомена, подставляем в мета данные город этого поддомена.
Шорткод используется в шапке и в футере, подставляет в зависимости от поддомена номер телефона и адрес филиала.

Когда пользователь заходит по адресу msk.site.ru, на сайте подставляется вся информация по филиалу Москвы(Номер телефона, город, мета теги). При этом все ссылки видут на основной домен, то есть пользователь находясь по адресу msk.site.ru нажимает на любую рубрику и оказывается на основном домене site.ru, а на основном домене находиться другой город и все данные меняются на другой город

Comment: [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710). Надо начать с вопроса - как сделан поддомен. И почему  на нём  ссылки на основной "не правильно"?

Comment: @SeVlad Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Как сделаны поддомкены так и не рассказано. Указанные плагины этого не делают. (и вообще нафига два с одинаковым функционалом?), что такое "function.php получаем" тоже не ясно. Ясно одно - поддомены сделаны неправильно. ..Потому что сделаны неквалифицированным любителем. А воще, насколько я смог наванговать - задача "поддоменности", несмотря на то, что довольно часто встречается, к сож не имеет вменяемых и простых решений.

Comment: А, ида.. Есть костыльное решение - динамически (в зависимости от запрошенного адреса) менять в конфиге WP_SITEURL и WP_SITEURL.